# Can we Autowired below class into Configuration class in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-profiles

I have a Component class and a config class,so can we autowire component class which uses @value internally,I tried using it but it throws exception,Can anyone please help me understanding

```
@Component
public class UserAction {
    @Value("${cp.user.name}")
    private String userName;

    @Value("${cp.user.actiontype}")
    private String actionType;

    @Value("${cp.user.designation}")
    protected Designation designation;

    public void show() {
        System.out.println(userName);
        System.out.println(actionType);
        System.out.println(designation);
    }
} 

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.example")
public class AppConfig {

@Autowired
UserAction userAction;
------
}
```

So My question is : can  I autowire my `UserAction` bean into my `AppConfig` class? 
I tried using it but its throwing exception,so can we autowire a component which internally uses `@value` :

```
    
Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'AppConfig ': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userAction'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userAction': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'cp.user.actiontype' in value "${cp.user.actiontype}"
```

Comment: I reformulated a little bit to keep the spring lexical.

Comment: Indeed Mustahsan. Please show the yaml/properties file that you use and its location.

Comment: Do you have the cp.user.actiontype in any application.yml? or application-[env].yml?

Comment: I have set the value in yml 
cp:
  user:
    actionType: get

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can `Autowire` beans in Configuration class, but the issue here is that a property in your bean has no value set in `properties/yml` file

`@Value("${cp.user.actiontype}")`

set the property `cp.user.actiontype` in your .properties or .yml file

Comment: I have set the value in yml 
cp:
  user:
    actionType: get

Comment: are indents proper? can you show us your application.yml?

Comment: it is still giving the error when I am trying with properties file
Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'serverConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dataSourceConstants'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'UserAction': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'cp.user.factory'

Comment: this is my application-dev.properties file


cp.user.actiontype= get
cp.user.name= hello
cp.user.designation= IT

and in my application.properties file I have added
spring.profiles.active=dev